# File upload on FTP server not working

Tags: c#, ftp

I am trying to upload a file to my ftp server. Unfortunately, the upload method seems to work but does not upload my selected file. Please, see my code below:

```
public void UploadFileToFTP(string source)
    {
        try
        {
            FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://xxx.bplaced.net/Test");
            ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("BN", "PW");

            ftp.KeepAlive = true;
            ftp.UseBinary = true;
            ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

            FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(source);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
            fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            fs.Close();

            Stream ftpstream = ftp.GetRequestStream();
            ftpstream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            ftpstream.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("Upload successful!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

public void button_Upload_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string sourcefilepath = @"C:\Users\MyPC\Desktop\Test\Texts\New.html";
        UploadFileToFTP(sourcefilepath);
    }
```

Please see this screenshot: What is meant by "Is a directory"?

[image: SCREENSHOT]

Error is clear: **Problem fixed.**

Comment: You should send the request by calling `ftp.GetResponse()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the [GetResponse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.getresponse(v=vs.110).aspx) method to actually send the ftp request. You have only prepared the request to be sent in your code.

To quote MSDN,

> GetResponse causes a control connection to be established, and might also create a data connection. GetResponse blocks until the response is received. To prevent this, you can perform this operation asynchronously by calling the BeginGetResponse and EndGetResponse methods in place of GetResponse.

So, After writing the file contents, call

```
ftp.GetResponse()
```

Comment: Okay, when I call `ftp.GetResponse();` before calling `ftpstream.Close();`, the tool freezes. Calling the method after it, nothing happens (same problem as before).

Comment: Tool freezes maybe because `GetResponse blocks until the response is received`. Refer the example in the link I provided in the answer and see if you have left out anything.

Comment: You would also probably have to use passive FTP mode (`ftp.UsePassive = true;`), because your firewall is most likely blocking the data channel connection from the FTP server.

Comment: Okay, thanks so far. I guess, I've got news for you. Please see my screenshot above.